# When try UnitTest, Jacoco error occurs. Even it does not used

Tags: android, unit-testing, jacoco

In Android source project when I try UnitTest, the Jacoco error occurs. But Jacoco is not used in source project.
In other developer's laptop, this issue does not occurs. Only my laptop displays this issue.
Below is the shorten error message.

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get
>   resource
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.7.9/org.jacoco.ant-0.7.9.pom'.
>
> Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException:
>   Could not GET
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.7.9/org.jacoco.ant-0.7.9.pom'.

The part of code which needs above resource is 
`java.net.Socket.connect()`

I searched in Google enough, but I couldn't find the answer.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You may use Jacoco by other dependencies, the possibility of your colleague has no this issue is he/she has cached this lib on his/her maven local (which will automatically be done by gradle), to figure out this issue, you can check here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.7.9, see the `Repositories` field, e.g., it available on `Central Repository`, then you can add `maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/' }` to your repositories in gradle, and resync the project

Comment: Thank you for comment. I added 'maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/' }' to build.gradle (project) as like below. But the result was same. 
What did I make mistake? - 

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://192.168.22.44:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local-asd'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://192.168.22.44:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local-asd'
        }
        maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/' }
    }
}

Comment: Try to change the order, move the new one before the `google()`. and for some cache issues of some old versions of Android Studio, you may need to click `Invalidate Caches / Restart` after the change